# Why is bootstrap horizontal form failing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Larger image if needed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84mux.png

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="officeSelection">Office</label>
                        <select data-ng-model="userSelections.office"
                                data-ng-options="o.name for o in officesInOrg"
                                name = "officeSelection"
                                id = "officeSelection"
                                class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Office"
                                ng-change = "officeSelected()">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. Why doesn't this maintain bootstrap [horizontal form format](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)?
2. How do I adjust size (input field width). Example in link above doesn't work (wrapping in more class="col-md-x" divs), but I think bootstrap might be failing overall here, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "input-group" vs "form-group" does matter. Just out of curiosity - class="form-control" is essential too. I guess input-group is just for [appending inputs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_input_groups.htm).

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="officeSelection" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 control-label">Office</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select data-ng-model="userSelections.officeId"
                            data-ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in selectionOptions.officesInOrg"
                            name = "officeSelection"
                            id = "officeSelection"
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Office"
                            ng-change = "officeSelected()">
                    </select>
                </div>
</div>
```